# How to find all classes decorated with a certain decoration?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.5

In Java we can find all classes that have a given annotation using "classpath scanning".

How can we do something similar in TypeScript? Is there a way to find all classes decorated with some decoration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example.  It assumes you have some way of referencing the scope.  The `magical` class decorator creates a string property called `isMagical` on the classes that it's applied to, and assigns the value of it as "indeed".  Then the `findMagicalInScope()` function loops through the properties on the specified scope (which is why the classes are all in a module) and sees if they have an `isMagical` property.

```
module myContainer {

  @magical
  export class foo {
  }

  export class bar {
  }

  @magical
  export class bas {
  }
}


function magical(item: any) {
  item.isMagical = "indeed";
}

function findMagicalInScope(theScope: any) {
  for(let prop in theScope) {
    if (theScope[prop]["isMagical"]) {
        console.log(`Is ${prop} magical?  ${theScope[prop]["isMagical"]}!`);
    } else {
      console.log(`${prop} is not magical.  :-(`);
    }
  }
}

findMagicalInScope(myContainer);
```

Will generate this output when run in Node.js:

```
Is foo magical?  indeed!
bar is not magical.  :-(
Is bas magical?  indeed!
```

Comment: Can we do this when the classes are in separate files?

Comment: Is there something like a global scope which can be used to search in all the files ?

Comment: if you're in the browser, you may be able to use the `window` object.  Otherwise, you'll have to collect them somehow like making all of the things you're interested in properties on an object.

Comment: Can I find accessors of a class some way similar?