# How to find all properties decorated with a certain decoration?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-decorator

I would like to add decorator to property already decorated with Angular `Input` decorator.
I need this, because I want to get some (those which are decorated) `Input` properties for specific `Component`.

I found very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30541388/how-to-find-all-classes-decorated-with-a-certain-decoration?rq=1), but with one big difference (I need it for property not class, so I can not introduce new variable on class as accepted answer proposed).

What I want to achieve is:

```
export class BaseComponent 
{   
    @Input() id: number;
    @Input() @isFilter id2: number;
    @Input() @isFilter id3: number;

    public getDefaultFilter(): object
    {
        let o: Partial<this> = {};

        //Assign all properties on this(self), which has decorator isFilter, to o!!   

        return o;    //o should be {id2: whatever_is_set, id3: whatever_is_set}
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just have an `@Input() myIds;` which is an object of ids and use that to get the specific ids?

Comment: Unfortunately not, because I need all those inputs for some filtering/operations in html.

Comment: But you could access them just as easily in the html via the object.

Comment: What if `Input` is another component, templateRef, string, array ... . Setting this `Input` parameter would become a mess.

Comment: Well that wasn't mentioned in the question. Right now you only have loose inputs that are supposed to be ids with `number` type. Maybe if you broaden the question it would be easier to understand what you're trying to achieve, cuz I don't think you can query for certain decorators as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `reflect-metadata` to store the decorated properties as metadata. E.g. the following code will store the names of all properties decorated with `@isFilter()`. You can then call `getFilteredProperties(this)` to get a shallow copy of `this` containing only the decorated properties.

```
import 'reflect-metadata';

const metadataKey = Symbol('isFilter');

function isFilter(): (target: object, propertyKey: string) => void {
  return registerProperty;
}

function registerProperty(target: object, propertyKey: string): void {
  let properties: string[] = Reflect.getMetadata(metadataKey, target);

  if (properties) {
    properties.push(propertyKey);
  } else {
    properties = [propertyKey];
    Reflect.defineMetadata(metadataKey, properties, target);
  }
}

function getFilteredProperties(origin: object): object {
  const properties: string[] = Reflect.getMetadata(metadataKey, origin);
  const result = {};
  properties.forEach(key => result[key] = origin[key]);
  return result;
}
```

You might also want to take a look at the [TypeScript documentation for decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html).

**Update**: Since Plunker appears to have some technical difficulties at the moment I used the opportunity to set up a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vqnkp6) for the code above. The old Plunker can still be found [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/XkDDy1MSSQxrD17HDXXH).

Comment: Hey, thank you. Works like a charm. I didn't have the the time to try it, so apologise for delay.

Comment: I tried running the plunker but I'm not getting anything. It crashes on some error
Console
 1
Error {originalErr: Error, constructor: Object}
originalErr: Error
<constructor>: "Error"
<constructor>: "Error"
name: "Error"

Comment: @ditoslav: I believe that Plunker is having technical difficulties right now. I wasn't even able to run a fresh Angular Plunker without getting weird errors. You can check the Stackblitz from the update as an alternative.

Comment: @kremerd This doesn't work properly with inheritance [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pdvmml?file=src/app/app.component.ts)